# file sharing solution for a small company network

Tags: permissions, samba, network-share, file-sharing

So we have a team of 9 people that need a file share on a linux server.
Every person has its own laptop. Most have a linux distribution on it and some have a windows OS. For security reasons the solution needs to support ACL. On top of that it should be easy to implement and maintain.

Ideas that came up up are Samba3 for file sharing but a problem remains.
Linux users have a UID/GID of 1000/1000. Ofcource on the server not everyone can have the same UID/GID. I do not know how it is with windows.
OpenLDAP could be a solution but it is to complex in setup and maintenance.
And I do not know if Samba3 user mapping can be used for this.

Is there simple solution to this ?
Maybe for linux only clients/server (windows support could be dropped) ?

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: Linux users should each have a different UID. Their GID would depend on what Groups they're in. I think you have some serious misunderstandings of how this works. Samba is definitely the right solution (in the general case); but I think you've got some configuration problems and will need someone who knows what they're doing to get it setup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For a team of 9 people, and with security in mind, if you can dedicate a small machine, I would suggest [freeIPA](http://www.freeipa.org). You will be able to

- setup an identity manager
- [automount](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/FreeIPA_Guide/automount.html)
- [samba/CIFS](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/FreeIPA_Guide/cifs.html) shares
- [NFS](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/FreeIPA_Guide/kerb-nfs.html)
- quite a lot more things related to security (SELinux mappings, `sudo` control,...)

It is all managed in a [kerberized](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/) LDAP directory server ([389](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Documentation)), but most of the complexity is hidden behind a friendly web UI. It is very well [documented](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/FreeIPA_Guide/index.html) and is quite easy to configure.

As a bonus, you can use the same identity manager to provide [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) for other applications.

Comment: Taking the features you listed it seems quite interesting. Is this software also available for ubuntu/debian ?